# How do you make a command with the word "with"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

The issue is that I want the users of my bot to be able to use the command '-with' as an abbreviation of "withdraw", but when I try to make a with command, I get an invalid syntax error because it thinks I'm trying to use the with statement. How can I fix this? Another question I have is how do I make function aliases? I want to make with an alias to withdraw, bal an alias to balance, dep an alias to deposit, and so on so that my users can use those abbreviations without me having to make each of those abbreviations into their own command.

```
import discord
import json
import os
import random
import sys
from discord.ext import commands
client = discord.Client()
sys.path.append(os.path.join(sys.path[0], "../"))
my_secret = os.environ['token']
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="-")

# [other code removed]

#-with
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1,5,commands.BucketType.user)
async def with(ctx, amount):
  await open_account(ctx.author)
  user = ctx.author
  users = await get_bank_data()
  amount = int(amount)
  if users[str(user.id)]["Bank"] < amount:
    await ctx.send(f"You don't have that many coins in your bank!")
  elif amount < 0:
    await ctx.send(f"No negative numbers!")
  elif amount == 0:
    await ctx.send(f"You want to withdraw 0 coins? Dummy.")
  else:
    users[str(user.id)]["Bank"] -= amount
    users[str(user.id)]["Wallet"] += amount
    await ctx.send(f"{amount} withdrawn!")
  await store_bank_data(users)
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
This code is not minimal, and it's not obvious where you hit the problem in over 150 lines of code (with no posted error message).

Comment: @Prune sorry, in the past i didnt include enough code so i wanted to make sure i didnt leave anything out. The problem occurs in the #Withdraw command section

Comment: I downvoted because there is too much unrelated code to the issue  in this question to make it underdanstable. Please edit to add only code that raises an error and the full traceback.

Comment: @May.D Will you upvote it now? :)

Comment: Absolutely not because this question reveals poor knowledge about Python and very few researching so I can't see how this is profitable to the community. Also though your answyer  is valid it doesnt improve the very low quality of that snippet.

Comment: Also, @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: @May.D *question reveals poor knowledge about Python* I disagree. I didn't know the answer off the top of my head either, and I use Python every other day. *very few researching* That I can agree with. But that threshold is largely arbitrary as well. Sometimes you don't even know that there's something you should look for. Good research skills take decades to develop.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica question reveals poor knowledge about Python > I would say that not knowing one of the few key words of the language reveals poor knowledge about it. I agree with you on "good research skills take decades to develop", but is that a reason to rush and post on SO ? Anyway, that is offtopic and should go to meta.

Answer (score 1):

It’s in the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html).

```
@bot.command(name='with')
@commands.cooldown(1,5,commands.BucketType.user)
async def _with(ctx, amount):
   …
```

Answer (score 0):

I know, it’s already approved, but my answer is this:

```py
@bot.command(aliases=["with", "w"]) #you can replace it by @client.command()
…
async def _with(ctx, amount):
    …
```